Common Questions | Wiki Answers
I am working on an answer to the question of how to identify this character, which it turns out is a really common question (I've asked it myself). I think the answer should be a community wiki (which we could then refer others to for assistance). The question is how to post the answer (when I'm finished) onto the community wiki to a question that hasn't been asked. Without the question itself being closed. 
One thing that has worked on other forums is a sticky note of some kind at the top. I know we also have FAQs so, I am wondering how to submit such an answer so that it can be considered for either the FAQs or as a community wiki? I think the community wiki idea would be the better of the two and perhaps a FAQs answer that links to the  community wiki (this would allow the community wiki to continue to grow in value without cluttering the main site). Users could then be directed to the community wiki for help when posting this kind of question.

Actually tool questions are off topic since the questions about Mandarin Resources was posted unless it's a specific and particular tool question. 
However we need to see if yours is a different case, since it's really specific. What kind of question did you have in mind? If you can make it fit the format of that resource question, you can post it directly there, otherwise, I'd like to see what you had in mind. :)

It's totally fine to answer your own question, so long as the question is on topic for the site. "What tools can I use to look up a character I don't know?" sounds on topic to me.
Post that question and answer on the main site. If you think an FAQ would be helpful then post one here in meta, and tag it faq. If that tag is restricted, then just flag the question for moderator attention with a note.
